# Dividing with rest 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a question. I have two numbers For example:

81 / 9 or 25 / 5 or 12 / 6 and so on.....
These two numbers appear randomly.

```
public SimpleSpriteSequence[] LeftNumbers;
public SimpleSpriteSequence RightNumbers;
public SimpleSpriteSequence NumberResul;
Randomizer NumberSequence = new Randomizer(1, 9);
    public void Getnumbers()
{
    if (!NumberSequence.randomRule.hasNumbersLeft())
    {
        NumberSequence.randomRule.Reset();
    }
    int FirstNumberIndex = NumberSequence.getRandom();
    LeftNumbers[0].setCurrentSpriteIndex(FirstNumberIndex);
    if (!NumberSequence.randomRule.hasNumbersLeft())
    {
        NumberSequence.randomRule.Reset();
    }
    int SecondNumberIndex = NumberSequence.getRandom();
    LeftNumbers[1].setCurrentSpriteIndex(SecondNumberIndex);
    if (!NumberSequence.randomRule.hasNumbersLeft())
    {
        NumberSequence.randomRule.Reset();
    }
    int RightNumberIndex = NumberSequence.getRandom();
    RightNumbers.setCurrentSpriteIndex(RightNumberIndex);

    int fIndex = 10 * (int)LeftNumbers[0].CurrentSpriteIndex;
    int sIndex = (int)LeftNumbers[1].CurrentSpriteIndex;
    int Number = fIndex + sIndex;
    int lIndex = (int)RightNumbers.CurrentSpriteIndex;
    result = Number / lIndex;
    Debug.Log(Number + ":" + lIndex + "=" + (Math.Truncate(result)));

  while(Math.Truncate(result) >= 10)
  {
      if (!NumberSequence.randomRule.hasNumbersLeft())
      {
          NumberSequence.randomRule.Reset();
      }
      FirstNumberIndex = NumberSequence.getRandom();
     LeftNumbers[0].setCurrentSpriteIndex(FirstNumberIndex);
      if (!NumberSequence.randomRule.hasNumbersLeft())
      {
          NumberSequence.randomRule.Reset();
      }
      SecondNumberIndex = NumberSequence.getRandom();
        LeftNumbers[1].setCurrentSpriteIndex(SecondNumberIndex);
        if (!NumberSequence.randomRule.hasNumbersLeft())
      {
          NumberSequence.randomRule.Reset();
      }
      RightNumberIndex = NumberSequence.getRandom();
        RightNumbers.setCurrentSpriteIndex(RightNumberIndex);

        fIndex = 10 * (int)LeftNumbers[0].CurrentSpriteIndex;
      sIndex = (int)LeftNumbers[1].CurrentSpriteIndex;
      Number = fIndex + sIndex;
      lIndex = (int)RightNumbers.CurrentSpriteIndex;
      result = Number / lIndex;
  }}
```

With this code they get operations like these:
13:6 = 2 or 24:7 = 3 and so on.
How do I get to do my operations with the rest 0?
For example: 81 : 9 or 24 : 8 or 12 : 6 and so on.
How to put this condition?

Comment: don't use int's for div

Comment: Ok but how to get those combinations that give the rest 0

Comment: [% operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator)

Comment: Ok, I do not think you understand what I have in mind

Comment: They have to give me only these operations:
18/9 or 24/4 or 36/9 or 15/3 and so on

Answer (score 3):

You should use the modulo operator which uses the `%` as operator-symbol. It returns the remainder of the division, instead of the result.

```
12 % 6 = 0
21 % 3 = 0
21 % 6 = 3
```

It's very nice to identify odd and even numbers.

[Further reading on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Modulo = RightNumber % LeftNumber;
while(Modulo != 0)
        {
            Getnumbers();
        }

Comment: Because you never update the value of `Modulo`. Do something like this `while(RightNumber % LeftNumber != 0) { GetNumbers(); }`

Comment: Division by 0 Error

Comment: Then check if LeftNumber is 0! `while(LeftNumber != 0 && RightNumber % LeftNumber != 0) { GetNumbers(); }`

Comment: "It does not work" is not sufficient information. _What_ does not work and why? What is your input? What is your expected output? What is your actual output? @GheorgheCiusca